# Divide items in each boxes that won't be 2 values has different items

Tags: algorithm

Given an **array a[]** has **n items** and **2*k boxes**. Each boxes can storage an infinity items, **but in only one a[i]**

> *Eg: if a[2]=5 and we divided to 3 boxes (b[1]=1,b[2]=2,b[3]=2), then 3 boxes 1,2,3 can't be storage any other value except a[2]*

When we finished dividing all a[i] to 2k boxes. **Maybe some box can be empty**. We take **k-minimum-box** and calculate their sum **(S)**. The question is: How to divide a[i] so that the sum **(S)** will be **maximum**.

**Limit: N, K<=1000; A[i]<=1000**

**Example:**

INP:
N=5; K=2; A[]={3,6,8,4,2}

OUT: 8

**Explain:**

- We divided a[3]=8 in 2 boxes (b[1]=4; b[2]=4)
- We put all a[4]=4 in 1 boxes (b[3]=4)
- We put all a[2]=6 in 1 boxes (b[4]=6)

So the value of boxes are: **{4,4,4,6}**; **2-minimum-box** is 4 and 4, the sum is 4+4=**8**

I have no idea about this problem except brute-forces (put each 1 in each box)